# Получения значения под "#" с ссылки [PHP]

Tags: php

Здрайствуйте столкунулся с проблемой что $_GET не выводит access_token с сылки: http://url.ru/index.php#access_token=token
Имено нужно вывести то что под # или как отправить запрос к vk.com чтoбы он дал в "&"

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php

Comment: @Visman как мне под $url выставить текуший? Ну тот который в адресной строке

Comment: @АлексейЛозовягин наверное что-то из переменной [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php) .....HTTP_REFERER или REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER что-то такое

Comment: Я вам дал ссылку на мануал. Если у вас имеется данная строка, то можете воспользоваться этой функцией, если же это у вас запрос из браузера на ваш сервер, то у вас проблема. Браузеры не отправляют содержимое якоря на сервер, обработать его можно в самом браузере с использованием js.